# Ethernet WAN cable not recognized by router, but recognized by everything else, and WAN port works

Tags: networking, router, ethernet, crossover-cable

I have an ISP-provided WAN cable (cat. 5E 2PR) going into my apartment, but my router (D-Link DIR-825ACG1 rev. G1) refuses to recognize it whenever I plug it into the WAN port. Specifically, it does not get any kind of connection on it - it just says cable unplugged.

Things I have checked:

- The cable works when plugged into my laptop. No problem with the cable itself.
- The WAN port on the router is functional - I have tried with a spare cable and it detects it correctly.

So, the problem only manifests itself when **this particular cable** is used with **this particular device**.

In the past I have used this same router in two different apartments and with two different ISPs, and it worked correctly.

I've also tried rebooting, resetting, and tinkering with the router's options for many times, to no avail.

I'm considering buying a crimping tool and some 8P8C connectors and re-crimping the cable as either pass-through or cross-over (I'm not sure which one it is at the moment).

What are some other things I can try, short of ringing up the ISP and asking they fix their cable themselves?

I am also considering there may be a configuration error on my part as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this by re-crimping my wire. Looks like it was crimped incorrectly for my configuration.